# Create a java executable with Eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, compiler-construction, ubuntu

This is a totally newbie question. I'm running Eclipse on Ubuntu. I created a test project that I want to compile to an executable (whataver the linux equivalent is of a Windows .exe file). Here's the contents of my program:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("You passed in: " + args[0]);

    }
}
```

I want to know how to compile it and then how to execute it from the command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to create an executable JAR file. Steps will follow shortly.

**Right click on the project and select JAR file under Export.**

[image]

**Enter the path where you want it to be saved. The example here is of Windows. Change according to your platform.**

[image]

**Click Next.**

[image]

**Edit the Main Class field by browsing and selecting the location of your class that contains the `main` method.**

[image]

**Run it**

To run the JAR file, open up a shell or command prompt and execute the following command:

`java -jar path/to/test.jar`

Comment: how come I would choose `jar file` over `runnable jar file`?

Comment: Try it. It's a new feature which didn't exist in earlier versions of eclipse.

Comment: I'll give you some bonus points if you tell me how to compile it with dependencies located elsewhere in the system. I added them to the build path, but get errors when I try to run it.

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse, choose file then export, and you will have to choose runnable jar. Also, you will be prompted to select the main class, MyTest in your case.

Comment: To execute it, type java -jar myapp.jar in the terminal.

Comment: This worked like a charm, The simple jar option was failing because it was not able to get the class path of dependent jar. Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipes tutorials are very helpful, if you do the "create a Hello World application" tutorial it will walk you through the process of setup the project, building the app and running the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know how to compile it ...

See other answers on how to get Eclipse to create a JAR file.

> ... and then how to execute it from the command line.

In the simple case, you execute it by running `java -jar yourApp.jar <args>`.

If your application depends on external libraries, then it is a bit more complicated ...

> how come I would choose jar file over executable jar file?

- Because a JAR file is portable, and a binary executable is not.
- Because JIT compiled code runs faster than code that is compiled ahead of time.
- Because the standard Java tool chain does not support creation of binary executables.  Ditto for Eclipse, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Marked solution does not work.
Use "runnable" jar instead and then `java -jar <jarfile>`