# Macosx: How to make a runnable jar file in eclipse?

Tags: java, executable-jar, sweethome3d

I will try to tell you exactly my problem, because I am stuck for more than 2 days now.
I am trying to make a project in Eclipse from existing source code (a program called sweethome3d) and then modify it. But, the problem even starts from even before modifying the code.

There are the steps that I am following:

1. File - import - existings projects into workspace.
2. I select the source code (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sweethome3d/files/SweetHome3D-source/SweetHome3D-3.3-src/SweetHome3D-3.3-src.zip/download)
3. Then, I try to export it into Runnable jar file
4. I have also to add some VM arguments in the command line when I try to execute it.
5. The runnable jar file does not run

   - in command line
   - with double click

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you run this application in Eclipse (between steps 2. and 3.)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a java executable with Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293321/create-a-java-executable-with-eclipse)

Comment: It runs perfectly in Eclipse.

Comment: Just do as in link @Nate posted, and tell us what goes wrong when you try to executed.

Comment: @Nate I tried to do it this way, but no luck.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jnlp/UnavailableServiceException
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
 at com.eteks.sweethome3d.SweetHome3DBootstrap.main(SweetHome3DBootstrap.java:90)                                                                 This is the error I get in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

If [this](http://sweethome3d.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sweethome3d/SweetHome3D/src/com/eteks/sweethome3d/SweetHome3DBootstrap.java?view=markup) is the same as the version of the code you're running, then `SweetHome3DBootstrap.java`, at line 90, is attempting to load `com.eteks.sweethome3d.SweetHome3D` dynamically.  This class needs the class `javax.jnlp.UnavailableServiceException`, which is from `javaws.jar`.

So, when you try to run your JAR, it's missing `javaws.jar` at runtime.  You'll need to either add it to the classpath (specified via the command-line when running, or via the JAR file's 'Class-Path:' manifest header), or re-package the classes from `javaws.jar` inside the JAR you're creating (like FatJar).

Answer (score 0):

It could be some dependency problem, hard to tell without knowing more. Try using [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) Eclipse plugin

Comment: It says that it is embedded in the eclipse that I am using.